# Is there any way to stream the screen of a iOS device remotely?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, remote-access

Person A is running Application XYZ on an iPod Touch with a internet connected wifi network. The network is set up with port forwarding/static ip so that there is a single IP for the iPod on the network.

Person B is connected to the internet and knows the IP/port info for Person A's iPod Touch.

Is there any way person B can view or control the screen of the iPod Device? Is there any way to "hack" this into an application, whether it would pass the app store review or not?

Comment: Try looking at AirPlay. There may be something there you might be able to use, though only compatible with AirPlay devices (Apple TV)

Comment: Isn't airplay on the same wifi network only?

Comment: There must be a way to do it, since it is what Apple seems to be using at their presentatios. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vBUjiG7e20

Comment: Apple's always been able to stream the screen even before Airplay was made. It's generally agreed that they use a hardware-modified device.

Comment: I'm working on Shou.TV, it can live stream the iOS and Android screen, e.g. https://shou.tv/v/yjsqqrz

Answer (score 2):

As Ron have said, you only can do this in the boundaries of your application.
I use this technique to demo my work on our daily meetings.
You can find a Gist of my solution here:
https://gist.github.com/1608099

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to stream and/or control remotely. But note this, it is only possible to stream and control within the boundaries of your app. and you cannot do anything remotely your app cannot do.

If you jailbreak your phone you can of course write fully remote control app and control your phone from where ever you'd like to.

Hope i helped

Comment: How would you go about handling the stream? We used to do mirroring with iPad 1, which involved creating a second display and updating it for every screen change event. I don't think that would translate well to a remote device...